# Windows Azure: how to update service definition for existing VM role?

Tags: networking, azure, virtual

I am reviewing Azure Connect, included in the Azure SDK 1.3. 
The goal is to connect an existing **VM role** machine to an already configured local endpoint. Note: using a Web role is not an option.

I need to make the configuration changes described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433071.aspx).

I can update the configuration file, but I first need to be able to update the service definition (.csdef) file to add this entry:

```
<Import moduleName="Connect" />
```

Problem: can I update the service definition file without Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can update the ServiceDefinition.csdef file with any text editor... and you can package any Windows Azure app with the cspack commandline tool.  (This does require the *SDK* to be installed, but not Visual Studio.)

Comment: Thanks, how can you download the existing csdef file?